How to import the published/installed version of the same package
My package has a dev dependency of the same package (the last published version).
What is the best way to refer the the installed (inside node_modules) version of said package?
I have an:
"exports": "./source/index.js"

field in my package.json for the consumers of the package to import. So if I do:
import {x} from "packageName"

it will resolve to .source/index.js. But I want the runtime to resolve to the copy inside node_modules.
Should I create a barrel file that exports this?:
"./node_modules/packageName/source/index.js"

I tried a more ergonomic way by importing from node_modules using package.json's
"imports": { #something: "./node_modules/packageName/source/index.mjs"}

but I think it's forbidden: I get
Error [ERR_INVALID_PACKAGE_TARGET]: Invalid "imports" target

